# Pattern matching using perl

Tags: perl

i have two files.

There are keywords in multiple lines in first file to be matched in multiple lines in second file.I need to get the count of these keywords.

the keywords i have created for example :

```
^.*\aB.c_Feg.*_vbn.*/ds_.*$ (^ and $ to indicate the beginning and end of line)
```

the lines in second file are for example:

```
P_csd.\[0] .i\-_\aB.c_Feg_90rAs (A#_vbn_T:) _345[/ds_] Asd_[0][7]
```

the code i have written is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$file= "$ARGV[0]";
open($File, '<', $file) or die "Can open '$file' for read: $!";
while ($var = <$File>)
{
push (@lines, $var);
}
$size = @lines;
$file1= "$ARGV[1]";
open($File1, '<', $file1) or die "Can open '$file1' for read: $!";
while ($var1 = <$File1>)
{
push (@lines1, $var1);
}
$size1 = @lines1;
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
$count=0;
for ( $i=0; $i<=$size; $i++)
{
  while ( $j<=$size1)
  {
    if ($lines[$i] == $lines1[$j])
    {
       $count++;
       $j++;
     }
    else 
    {
         $j++;
    }
   }
print "$lines[$i] = $count\n";
$count = 0;
}
```

i am not getting the expected results. 
The first keyword I am getting some value. The rest 0. 
The last keyword  I am getting
Keyword =0
                 =0

Could somebody help me as to where I am going wrong?

#### Readable Perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$file = "$ARGV[0]";

open( $File, '<', $file ) or die "Can open '$file' for read: $!";

while ( $var = <$File> ) {
    push( @lines, $var );
}

$siwe  = @lines;
$file1 = "$ARGV[1]";

open( $File1, '<', $file1 ) or die "Can open '$file1' for read: $!";

while ( $var1 = <$File1> ) {
    push( @lines1, $var1 );
}

$siwe1 = @lines1;
$i     = 0;
$j     = 0;
$count = 0;

for ( $i = 0; $i <= $siwe; $i++ ) {

    while ( $j <= $siwe1 ) {

        if ( $lines[$i] == $lines1[$j] ) {
            $count++;
            $j++;
        }
        else {
            $j++;
        }
    }

    print "$lines[$i] = $count\n";
    $count = 0;
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: Indenting is not just an option but a mark of respect

Comment: first keyword i get some value but the remaining keywords in the array i get 0. the last keyword i get like

Comment: the last keyword i get like 
keyword= 0
             = 0

Comment: `while ($var1 = <$File1>)
{
push (@lines1, $var1);
}` is normally written as `@lines1 = <$File1>`

Comment: Borodin and Gilles this is the first time I have written a script. It definitely makes sense where I use it though. Probably I should have posted a more readable one, I do agree with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ALWAYS 'use strict; use warnings;' at the top of your script.  This will catch a lot of problems.

It looks like you're using c-style for loops, but don't reset the inner loop to 0, so it will only ever check the first keyword against the whole second file.  Also, you're using the numeric == to compare strings.  Instead you should use 'eq' to compare strings.  Adding 'use warnings;' to the top of your script will print a warning message for this type of problem.

You could use the perlish form and avoid using indexes at all:

```
chomp @lines; # remove line endings
chomp @lines1;
for my $kw(@lines){
   my $count = 0;
   for my $text(@lines1){
       $count ++ if $kw eq $text;
   }
   print "$kw = $count\n";
}
```

Hope this helps.